# Possible to get words matched fuzzily by MongoDB full text search?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I'm writing a UI that presents the results of a MongoDB full text search query, visually highlighting the matched search terms in each result; this works well enough for full word or phrase matches, but not for partial/fuzzy matches.

For example, if I search for "delete" a will get a search result that contains "deletion", which does not contain the full word "delete" and therefore won't be highlighted if I merely highlight the full search term matches. I do want the partial matches, though.

Is there any way to project the set of matched words/substrings when I execute the query?

I've so far been unable to find anything in the docs that hints at this being possible, but I thought it worth asking around. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know there is a way to calculate match % but not sure if there is something that can highlight matched words !! Good luck ..

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the meta score, which is helpful. Still, it's looking more and more like I might have to repeat the fuzzy matching myself client-side to get the results I want. Still hoping to be proven wrong by some pearl of esoteric mongodb wisdom from a passerby, though :-)

Comment: mongodb atlas has fuzzy searches though: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/full-text-search/term/#fuzzy-example

Comment: @Astro, the problem isn't getting fuzzy search to work. What it's missing is a list of words that mongodb thought were fuzzy matches in each of the query results, for the purposes of highlighting all matched substrings in the UI that displays the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mongo DB Atlas feature where you can search your text based on different [Analyzers](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/) that MongoDB provides. And you can then do a search like this: Without the fuzzy object, it would do a full-text-match search.

```
$search:{
 {
  index: 'analyzer_name_created_from_atlas_search',
  text: {
    query: 'Text to do a full match or fuzzy match with',
    path: 'sentence',
    fuzzy:{
      maxEdits: 2   #max 2 is allowed
    }
  }
 }
}
```