# MongoDB Quick Word Comparison

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Every entry in my collection has an array of keywords, and I've got an aggregate that can pull all entries that contain similar keywords (using $size and $setIntersection), but I'm wondering if the query times are suffering from doing a bunch of string compares, but I can't find a way to do a fast 1-1 pairing of each word to a unique number or id.

I was looking into indexes, but either I don't understand them, or they won't help me here. My other thought was a second collection that is just a table of words, each with a unique ID, and before a create an entry, I pull the IDs of the relevant words and use them as my comparison array, but there seems like there has got to be a better way to do that.

This is my current aggregate in pymongo:

```py
results = collection.aggregate(
    [
        {"$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {"$gte": [
                    {"$size": {"$setIntersection": ["$a", usr_tags]}},
                    {"$subtract": [{"$min": [{"$size": "$Tags"}, len(usr_tags)]}, 1]}
                ]},
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }}
    ]
)
```

TL;DR: Is there a fast way to create a 1:1 pairing of words to _id's, and is it faster to do that than to use string compares for my aggregates

I am using Python, so if you have a module that can quickly pair any word with a unique number, I'm all ears

Comment: What kind of word comparisons are you trying? Is it looking for almost same spelling words? If thats the case, you can use ```$search``` with fuzzy options. You can refer an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644884/6503329) here for it.

Comment: fuzzy search would be nice, but im way more focused on speed